# move files based on pattern with zsh/zmv

Tags: zsh, rename

How could I move files to subdirectories based on the common part of their names?

For example, with files named as `comment_LastName.pdf` and `comment_LastName.md` and sub-directories named as `FirstName_LastName/` where all `FirstName` and `LastName` vary, how do I move files `comment_X.pdf` to subdirectory `Mister_X/` ? (but for all files / directories at once)

Here's an unsuccessful attempt with `zmv` but I can't figure out the proper command...

`zmv -n 'comment_(*).(pdf|md)' '*_$1/$f'`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the destination operand for zmv gets quoted if you introduce any backreferences such as `$1` and `$f`, so you can't add globbing in this case. The best option I found to solve this problem was to use the `-p` flag and give `zmv` a custom defined `mv` function.

This is what I came up with:

```
mv2 () {
    local dir
    dir=(*_$3:h) 
    mv $1 $2 $dir[1]/$3:t
}
zmv -p mv2 'comment_(*).(pdf|md)' '$1/$f'
```

In the `mv2` function, we create an array of the directories you want to put the files in. Then in the actual `mv` command, we tag on the filenames to the directory array components. Globbing for the destination directories has to separated since these files don't exist yet. The globbing would fail otherwise.